# Is it possible to fire an event after returning from a function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, dom-events

I'm working on a JavaScript project that makes use of a REST API I wrote a while back. I am using Axios for making get/post/put/delete requests to the API. I have an async function "delete":

```
async delete(resource, data) {
    try {
        var resp = await axios.delete(this.buildUrl(resource), { data });
        var event = new CustomEvent('ApiDELETE', {
            detail: {
                resource_type: resource,
                request_params: data,
                response: resp.data
            }
        });
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
        return resp.data;
    } catch(error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to fire a CustomEvent right after the call to delete returns. For example, I have a function that I want to run, but I need to make sure it waits until a specific resource is deleted and the response has been processed. Because of this, I have an event listener on the ApiDELETE event that will run when the event fires.

```
var theDataWeNeed = await api.delete("resource", data);

document.addEventListener("ApiDELETE", (event) => {
    console.log(theDataWeNeed);
});
```

The problem with this is that I need to wait until `resp.data` has been returned, because the function the event handler runs relies on the variable that is set to the return value of the `delete` function.

Is it possible to always fire the event AFTER the `delete` function returns?

P.S. Yes, I know that in this specific example, I could just forget the event entirely and put the console log right after the await statement. However, I'm looking for a more robust solution that will allow me to hook into these events.

Comment: But isn't the `resp.data` already in the event payload? You could always just do `theDataWeNeed = e.detail.response;`

Comment: Can you not change this to a promise and trigger it all in the resolve?

Comment: To Raymonds point, what extra info/data gets set? Is it that the await side also does something and you want to wait for that first? If not then you have the `detail` object that you can assign more data to.